# Python GetLogicalDrives Bitwise AND

Tags: python, bitwise-and

i have some questions about the following code.

```
from win32 import win32file
drives = []
drivebits=win32file.GetLogicalDrives()
for d in range(1,26):

    mask=1 << d
    if drivebits & mask:
        drname='%c:\\' % chr(ord('A')+d)
        t=win32file.GetDriveType(drname)
        if t == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
            drives.append(drname)
print(drives)
```

1-When you use the GetLogicalDrives from win32 module it returns an integer.Can someone explain why?

2-Why the loop's range is between 1 and 26?

3-Whats the reason of the bitwise AND?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `win32` module is a really low-level wrapper around the Win32 API, so usually you can look at the Windows documentation of the function name and get the info you need. You can find the [documentation for GetLogicalDrives here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972(v=vs.85).aspx)

To answer your question:

1. The integer corresponds to the available drives:  each available drive gets 1 bit.  So if no drives are available, you'd get `0`, assuming a 32-bit integer) back.  If every drive was available, you'd get `0b11111111111111111111111111` (in binary)
2. There are 26 letters, so it loops through 26 numbers.  **Actually, the code you posted is only looping from 1 to 25, and I think that is a bug.  It should just be `range(26)`.**
3. The bitwise and is to check the individual bits of the returned integer.  Remember, each *bit* of the integer corresponds to a drive letter.  Let's say, for example, that your C, D, and G drives are available.  You can visualize the returned value like this, where the first row is the *potential* drives, and the second row is the *returned value in binary*:

   ```
   ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA # drive the bit corresponds to
   00000000000000000001001100 # returned value, in binary, if C, D, and G are available
   ```

To check if drive A is available, you need to check that the smallest bit is 1.  *The way to check individual bits is with a bitwise and.*  To do the check for the smallest bit, you would do `drivebits & 1`, to check drive B, you need to check the second bit: `drievebits & (1 << 1)`. To check C, you need the third bit: `drivebits & (1 << 2)`. And so on.

Some example returns:

If you only have drive C available, `GetLogicalDrives` would return `0b100` (binary), or `4` (decimal).  If C and D were available, you'd get `0b1100` (binary), or `12` (decimal).

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. But about the bitwise AND i mean this is a code to check if any removable drive is plugged so why should we make a bitwise AND ? Lets say i got only drive C available so i got 0b100 as my drivebits why should i write the "if drivebits & mask:" line ?

Comment: @M.Han: I updated my answer.  It should make more sense now.

Comment: I totally got it. Thanks a lot!